# avoid imported pdf page taking whole page embedding pdf within text

Tags: environments

I'm using `\usepackage{pdfpages}` to drop charts into a `.tex` file.
It seems that this is generating a lot of wasted space.

Anyone with a suggested fix?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please note that it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Basically show the problem instead of describing it.

Comment: `pdfpages` is *only* for including whole pages. Use the `graphicx` package and the command `\includegraphics` to include images within a page.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding the answer given in the comments, you can include a single page of a pdf document using `\includegraphics[page=1]{external_file.pdf}`.

This will include that page of the pdf as an image into the current document, not as a separate page. However, the external page will be included with all its margins, so perhaps you'll get still a lot of wasted space.

You have two alternatives to deal with this issue:

1. Edit the external pdf file and crop the unwanted margins.
2. Use options `clip` and `trim` or `bb` in `\includegraphics` (see `graphicx` documentation). This allows you to do the "cropping" at including time, and can be a good form of automation if all your external pdf figures have the same amount of margin.